# Data Binding: Cannot find symbol class BR

Tags: android, android-databinding

I try to use Data Binding in my existing project, but I can't get it to build.

Using in Project `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    //Data Binding Beta
    classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc4"

    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.7+'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

applying

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'`
```

and in Module:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    apt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:1.0-rc1+'
}
```

I tried to use Data Binding with RecyclerView/Fragment/ViewHolder/Adapter..
I use Android Studio 1.4.1.
With compileSdkVersion 23 and buildToolsVersion "23.0.1".
I tried it without apt, different gradle versions, proof read my classes/xml..
I also use still Butterknife(since my project is too big to change everything at once) and other (but unrelevant) libraries.
I synced and rebuild my project, I closed/opened Android Studio, I tried to invalidate caches. I build a 'fresh' example from start, which worked fine.

My getter Methods in my "data class" are @Bindable.

Also, the databinding package is not created. (error message says it doesn't exist) and `Error:cannot generate view binders java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -21`

Comment: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-stringindexoutofboundsexception-how-to-solve-stringindexoutofboundsexception/

Comment: Since this error is thrown by data binding I have no line where I can start searching for that error, and it appeared after adding data binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the `Error:cannot generate view binders java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -21` error almost everytime when I tried to use a `ObservableList` with custom objects. But I found out, that almost everytime I forgot a `>` after my type. Silly me.
So, my solution was to check for it:

```
    <data>

        <import type="android.databinding.ObservableArrayList"/>

        <variable
            name="dices"
            type="ObservableArrayList&lt;Dice>" /> //don't forget the '>' after Dice
    </data>
```

Answer (score 18):

**For AndroidX projects:**

I faced this issue after migrating to androidx, this is how I solved it.

- BR class is auto-generated from data binding when you rebuild the project.
- But if the error persists, add the code below in
  your imports then rebuild the project.

  ```
  import androidx.databinding.library.baseAdapters.BR;
  ```

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. @HemangNirmal

Comment: Can't believe that worked. The absolute state of Android studio, smh.

Answer (score 6):

I have had different issues with DataBinding similar to your, for instance that Android Studio cannot find the generated Binding classes like "MainActivityBinding". Restarting Android Studio solved it for me.

As to the BR classes, I have had issues with them not being found, but usually it was because of an error I had made in the layout-class. For instance binding to a field that does not exist. Make sure everything else is correct, then restart Android Studio.

Comment: Restarting android studio did the job for me. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I am using data binding from long time, and I came up with some key points, that can help you too.

**This answer will help you generate `ViewDataBinding`, `BindingResource(BR)` class & layout variables in `ViewDataBinding` class.**

#### 6 Tips not to stuck in binding.

**(1)** You should have **data binding enabled** in `build.gradle`. If not then add this and **Sync**.

```
android {
...
   dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
...
}
```

**(2)** Now if you want data binding class to be generated then you should **wrap `xml layout` with data binding** (**`<layout`** tag). Something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**(3)** Now your data binding class should be generated.

> If your layout name is in **snake case** `activity_main.xml` then data binding class
>   will be generated in **camel case** like `ActivityMainBinding`.

Sometimes when you type **`ActivityMai...`**, then it **does not show suggestion**, but that **does not mean** class is **not generated**. In that case you should **type full name** of expected generated class. Like type `ActivityMainBinding` and it **will show import popup**. (That's what i faced many times.)

**(4)** If still your class is not generated. (Some time when we paste layout file, then it happens). Then **Rebuild Project** from `Build> Rebuild` (*Not Build or Make project*). It will generate your data binding class. (**Rebuild does Magic for me all times.**)

**(5)** If you have created an **`<variable`** in your layout and it **does not show up its setter and getter** in data binding class, then **follow 4th point**.

**(6)** Still if your class is not generating then you should **check if build is not failing due to an error** in your layout file. Data binding class will generate with a successful build.

This is all what i do to solve my data binding errors. If you get any further issue, you can comment here.

Comment: I already have enabled dataBinding enabled true but still coming this error @Khemraj

Answer (score 4):

After update **Android Studio** **to version 2.3** and **Gradle 3.3** I had this error and the solution for me was add this to my **build.gradle(app)** file

```
apt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.0'
```

Comment: I suppose one should move away from apt to annotation processor? Instead use this: `annotationProcessor 'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.0'`

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the plugin:

```
kotlin-kapt
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes DataBinding will show unrelated errors but in my case I forgot to add
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
in your Gradle App file

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem when tried to migrate to AndroidX.

Initial parameters: AStudio 4.0, Gradle Plugin v4.0.0, Gradle v6.1.1.

I replaced in the app build.gradle config:

```
dataBinding { enabled = true }
```

to

```
dataBinding.enabled = true
```

And updated:

butterknife 9.0.0 => 10.2.1

dagger 2.7 => 2.27 (necessary)

Answer (score 0):

Error might actually not be due to databinding. Javac truncates error logs, hence might not display actual issue.

Check out this link.
https://movieos.org/2017/android-room-data-binding-compile-time-errors/

Answer (score 0):

Convert your project to android x and then import BR class from below package
import androidx.databinding.library.baseAdapters.BR

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have update my code from project which are build on higher version of the Android studio. Then I upgrade my android studio from 3.3.2 to 3.5.3 and problem resolve.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a few **static imports** for a few variables that were removed later, and on project reload android studio tried to import them everything went apart.

So **look carefully for the most recent changes** in your project especially any static imports you will surely figure out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) in my application, and this problem was being caused by a missing `@NonNull` annotation on the primary key of an entity. Adding the annotation solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but I hope I can help someone after me trying to solve the error after like an hour of confusion.

This error appears in my project when duplicating the dependency providing method while using dagger hilt, for example:

`@Singleton @Binds public abstract ISettingsCacheDataSource provideSettingsCacheDataSource(SettingsCacheDataSourceImpl dataSource);`

Duplicating this code made this error show up, and removing the duplicate or fixing it with other dependency fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason BRs might not be generated, your Android Gradle Plugin is older than 4.0.0 and you are not enabling data binding like this:

```
buildFeatures{
    dataBinding = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I add namespace and it resolve my issue.

```
android {
    //..
    namespace = "your.package"
    android.buildFeatures.dataBinding = true
    }
```