# android Data Binding - command-line build cannot find BR.java file

Tags: android, data-binding, android-gradle-plugin

When using Android Data Binding functionality by opt-ing in in the *app/build.gradle* file

```
android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

invoking the Gradle build from the command line using either the `gradlew` wrapper script or the latest version with a local install fails due to an inability to find the generated `BR.java` file:

```
rm -rf build && gradle --stop && gradle clean build
...
:app:compileDevelopmentDebugJavaWithJavac
app/src/main/java/com/mydomain/MyActivity.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
import com.mydomain.BR;
                   ^
```

... but Android Studio is able to reference the file just fine, **after** selecting `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart` from its menus.

Indeed, after the failure to build from the command line, the file exists on disk:

```
app $ find ./ -name BR.java
.//build/intermediates/classes/development/debug/com/mydomain/BR.java
```

Attempts to force it into the source set Java directories in the *app/build.gradle* file did not help matters at all:

```
android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def intermediatesDir = "$project.buildDir/intermediates/classes/${variant.dirName}/"
        android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += intermediatesDir
    }
}
```

I would very much like to continue building my project from the command line so that the application is not beholden to Android Studio to build.

How can I build from the command line while referencing `BR.java` in my source files when using Android Data Binding functionality?

Comment: can you share your full gradle build file? Might be a problem with the annotation processor setup.

Comment: I'll see if I can dig it up out of a branch somewhere

Comment: branch was long-gone =/

Comment: I solved the problem adding apt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.0' to build.gradle(app). http://stackoverflow.com/a/42843579/2091181

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Dagger? If so, please check: https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/issues/38/android-apt-breaks-brand-new-data-binding#comment-18504545

Comment: there are no dagger dependencies reported by Gradle for any build target