# Android MVVM : cannot generate view binders

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, android-databinding

I am getting an error like

```
Error:cannot generate view binders java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -8
```

Few minutes before, my code was running well and I was able to run the project. I have tried many solutions as given over stackoverflow but not able to find out actual solution to this problem.

My app level gradle is like

```
android {

compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

defaultConfig {

    applicationId "com.xyz.abc"
    minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
    targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}

dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}

compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.8
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
  }

}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {

  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'

  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Any input from your side is highly appreciated.

Comment: check the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33343411/data-binding-cannot-find-symbol-class-br/33414765

Comment: @Anonymous not working for me

Answer (score 1):

I am to find the solution for my above problem. This is some silly mistake I have done in my layout file under  tag. I have written code like

```
<variable
        name="deliveryPreferences"
        type="java.util.ArrayList&gt;String&lt;" />
```

instead of

```
<variable
        name="deliveryPreferences"
        type="java.util.ArrayList&lt;String&gt;" />
```

The difference here is for **>** and **<** text placement. I got confused between these two. Right solution is second one if some want to send arraylist from yout Java file to xml file.